# Is it possible to use CSS when coding with Razor HTML helpers

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am pretty new to MVC and just learning by example, so far I was able to do

```
@Html.RadioButton("settings", "UpdateEmail")
```

But is there a way like extra params maybe so I can also set some `outline:none` and `alignment` attributes for it?

In Google I found this example but he is not passing CSS either: `http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-radiobutton-radiobuttonfor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each HTMLHelper in Razor has the `htmlProperty` parameter, which accept an object and will print the properties of this object inside the `html`.

So, if you want to set a CSS class, you can do this:

```
@Html.RadioButton("settings", "UpdateEmail", new {@class = "myCssClass"})
```

Which will become into this:

```
<input type="radio" name="settings" value="UpdateEmail" class="myCssClass">
```

And you can set any property in this way:

```
@Html.RadioButton("settings", "UpdateEmail", new {@class = "myCssClass", style="width: 100px", disabled="disabled"})
```

Note: The `@` before the property named `class` is required because class is a reserved word, so using `@class` allows you tu use this word.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do it like this:

@Html.RadioButton("settings", "UpdateEmail", new { @class="inputclass" })

or

@Html.RadioButton("settings", "UpdateEmail", new { style="outline: none;" })